# Displaying Ads on a custom canvas

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application in which I'd like to incorporate ads. The thing is, I'm not really sure how to add ads on a custom canvas. The canvas is not a part of any layout and is the only object drawn to the screen programmatically

```
setContentView(canvas);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a relative layout and add the canvas and the adview to the relative layout like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rl.addView(canvas);
    rl.addView(adView);
    setContentView(rl);
}
```

This will work assumin that canvas is a surface view, right? Also keep all the other code you used to initialize the surface view and add view, just add this code in main activity but keep all the rest except setContentView().   Hope this works!

Comment: I guess this helped, thanks for accepting it, if its not too much to ask could u upvote it, I would like the rep, thx :P